# Losing image quality with apache deflate and mem_cache

Tags: image, apache, debian, mod-deflate, mod-cache

I'm running my website under Debian 7,
The following apache modules were enabled : mem_cache, cache, deflate
But the problem is, all images was losing their quality!
When i check my physical file, the quality is perfect.
I disabled all of those three modules, but the problem persist!
How can i get my inital quality please?
Thank you

Comment: a good start would be to ask the question on the proper forum, e.g. [sf]

Comment: Don't use Opera Mini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was a network problem!